# Bootstrap: Trying to overwrite 1px .container:before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

So in my `.container` I see that there is `1px` padding on the top and bottom of the `<div>` which is coming from my Bootstrap include in my RoR project. Even a band-aid solution would be desirable.

The css from Bootstrap that matches these `:before` and `:after` selectors are the following:

```
media="all"
*:before, *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box; 
 }




media="all"
.container:before, .container:after {
content: " ";
display: table; 
}
```

What would be the inverse of these operations? Or how could I simply overwrite them before I load them in my `application.css.scss` file?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the clearfix that Bootstrap adds to the `.container` and other elements like `.row`, see [mixins/clearfix.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins/clearfix.less) in [Bootstrap's repository](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/).

The `:before` part is used to keep the margins from collapsing and the `:after` part is used to contain for example the floating columns inside a `.row` element. See [Nicolas Gallagher's clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) post for a more complete explanation.

If you don't want to keep the top margin from collapsing you can overwrite it, probably by simply setting `.container:before { display: none; }`